# Output values from Python list into csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, file-io

I have a function which returns value in the below format:

```
["Stage 1 : Package Description: Blisters are made in a cold-forming process from an aluminium base web. Each tablet isfilled into a separate blister and a lidding foil of aluminium is welded on. The blistersare opened by pressing the tablets through the lidding foil. Values: ['Blister', 'Foil', 'Aluminium']", "Stage 2 : Package Description: The tablets are filled into box cylindrically shaped bottles made of white colouredpolyethylene. The volumes of the bottles depend on the tablet strength and amount oftablets, ranging from 20 to 175 ml. The screw type cap is made of white colouredpolypropylene and is equipped with a tamper proof ring. Values: ['Bottle', 'Cylindrically shaped Bottles', 'Polyethylene'] Colour: White", "Stage 3 : Package Description: The tablets are filled into box cylindrically shaped bottles made of white colouredpolyethylene. The volumes of the bottles depend on the tablet strength and amount oftablets, ranging from 20 to 175 ml. The screw type cap is made of white colouredpolypropylene and is equipped with a tamper proof ring. Values: ['Bottle', 'Screw Type Cap', 'Polypropylene'] Colour: White"]
```

So for, some Stages "Colour" will be present and for some Stages "Colour" will not be present. I want to extract these values into a csv where the columns should be as follows:

EXPECTED OUTPUT IN CSV:

```
StageNumber  PackageDescription           Values1    Values2                        Values3       Colour
1.          Blisters are made in a ...    Blister    Foil                          Aluminium             

2.          The tablets are filled ...    Bottle   Cylindrically shaped Bottles     Polyethylene   White
```

Code till now:

```
paragraphs = ['The tablets are filled into cylindrically shaped bottles made of white coloured\npolyethylene. The volumes of the bottles depend on the tablet strength and amount of\ntablets, ranging from 20 to 175 ml. The screw type cap is made of white coloured\npolypropylene and is equipped with a tamper proof ring.', 'PVC/PVDC blister pack', 'Blisters are made in a cold-forming process from an aluminium base web. Each tablet is\nfilled into a separate blister and a lidding foil of aluminium is welded on. The blisters\nare opened by pressing the tablets through the lidding foil.', '\n']

final_ref = [['Blister', 'Foil', 'Aluminium'], ['Blister', 'Base Web', 'PVC/PVDC'], ['Bottle', 'Cylindrically shaped Bottles', 'Polyethylene'], ['Bottle', 'Screw Type Cap', 'Polypropylene'], ['Blister', 'Base Web', 'PVC'], ['Blister', 'Base Web', 'PVD/PVDC'], ['Bottle', 'Square Shaped Bottle', 'Polyethylene']]

colours = ['White', 'Yellow', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Green', 'Black', 'Brown', 'Silver', 'Purple', 'Navy blue', 'Gray', 'Orange', 'Maroon', 'pink', 'colourless', 'blue']

TEXT_WITHOUT_COLOUR = 'Stage {counter} : Package Description: {sen} Values: {values}'

TEXT_WITH_COLOUR = TEXT_WITHOUT_COLOUR + ' Colour: {colour}'

counter = 1
result = []


def is_missing(words, sen):
    for w in words:
        if w.lower() not in sen.lower():
            return True
    return False


for words in final_ref:
    for sen in paragraphs:
        if is_missing(words, sen):
            continue

        kwargs = {
            'counter': counter,
            'sen': sen,
            'values': str(words)
        }

        if words[0] == 'Bottle':
            for wd in colours:
                if wd.lower() in sen.lower():
                    kwargs['colour'] = wd
                    break
            text_const = TEXT_WITH_COLOUR
        else:
            text_const = TEXT_WITHOUT_COLOUR

        result.append(text_const.format(**kwargs).replace('\n', '').replace('\t', ''))
        counter += 1

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I propose is not the most correct, however it works. You could try to improve it and adapt it to your needs.

```
response = ["Stage 1 : Package Description: Blisters are made in a cold-forming process from an aluminium base web. Each tablet isfilled into a separate blister and a lidding foil of aluminium is welded on. The blistersare opened by pressing the tablets through the lidding foil. Values: ['Blister', 'Foil']", "Stage 2 : Package Description: The tablets are filled into box cylindrically shaped bottles made of white colouredpolyethylene. The volumes of the bottles depend on the tablet strength and amount oftablets, ranging from 20 to 175 ml. The screw type cap is made of white colouredpolypropylene and is equipped with a tamper proof ring. Values: ['Bottle', 'Cylindrically shaped Bottles', 'Polyethylene'] Colour: White", "Stage 3 : Package Description: The tablets are filled into box cylindrically shaped bottles made of white colouredpolyethylene. The volumes of the bottles depend on the tablet strength and amount oftablets, ranging from 20 to 175 ml. The screw type cap is made of white colouredpolypropylene and is equipped with a tamper proof ring. Values: ['Bottle', 'Screw Type Cap', 'Polypropylene'] Colour: White"]


def get_stage(word):
    return word.split("Stage ")[1].split(" : Package")[0]


def get_description(word):
    return word.split("Package Description: ")[1].split(" Values: ")[0]


def get_values(word):
    return eval(word.split("Values: ")[1].split(" Colour: ")[0])


def concatenate_values(values, max_length):
    concatenated_values = ""
    for idx, value  in enumerate(range(max_length)):
        try:
            concatenated_values += values[idx] + ";"
        except:
            concatenated_values += ";"

    return concatenated_values

def get_colour(word):
    colour = word.split(" Colour: ")
    if len(colour) == 1:
        return ""
    else:
        return colour[1]


def create_header(max_length):
    values_header = ""
    for i in range(max_length):
        values_header += "Values" + str(i + 1) + ";"

    return "StageNumber;PackageDescription;" + values_header + "Colour"


def get_length_values(response):
    max_length = 0
    for word in response:
        values = get_values(word)
        if len(values) > max_length:
            max_length = len(values)

    return max_length

def get_formatted_csv_array(response):
    formatted_csv_array = []
    for id, word in enumerate(response):
        stage = get_stage(word)
        description = get_description(word)
        values = concatenate_values(get_values(word), get_length_values(response))
        colour = get_colour(word)
        formatted_csv_array.append(stage + ";" + description + ";" + values + colour)

    return formatted_csv_array


file = open('output.csv', mode='w')
file.write(create_header(get_length_values(response)) + "\n")
for row in get_formatted_csv_array(response):
    file.write(row + "\n")
file.close()
```

I hope I've helped